# returning something not needed (for compiler)

Tags: java

In this code:

Can anyone explain me .. why we need to return "Error" ?

And in some integer methods (not in this code) .. why `return 0` is used?

```
package chapter4;

import java.util.Scanner;
class DateThirdTry
{
    private String month;
    private int day;
    private int year; //a four digit number.
    public void setDate(int newMonth, int newDay, int newYear)
    {
        month = monthString(newMonth);
        day = newDay;
        year = newYear;
    }
    public void writeOutput()
    {
        System.out.println(month + " " + day + ", " + year);
    }
    public String monthString(int monthNumber)
    {
        switch (monthNumber)
        {
        case 1:
            return "January";
        case 2:
            return "February";
        case 3:
            return "March";
        case 4:
            return "April";
        case 5:
            return "May";

        case 6:
            return "June";
        case 7:
            return "July";
        case 8:
            return "August";
        case 9:
            return "September";
        case 10:
            return "October";
        case 11:
            return "November";
        case 12:
            return "December";
        default:
            System.out.println("Fatal Error");
            System.exit(0);
            return "Error"; //to keep the compiler happy
        }
    }
}
class DateThirdTryDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DateThirdTry date = new DateThirdTry( );
        int year = 1882;
        date.setDate(6, 17, year);
        date.writeOutput( );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reformat this code with the correct indentation. It is a bit hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

1) Java will give a compiler error if a function has an exit path that doesn't return a value.  Not returning a value is illegal in Java.  Arguably a Good Thing.

2) In this case, your function calls "System.exit()" instead of returning a value.  You know the program isn't going to execute the 'return "Error"', but you need to add it to satisfy the compiler.

3) The *appropriate* thing to do, however, is to throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy, your method `monthString()` returns a... `String`:

```
public String monthString(int monthNumber)
```

So, you have to return a `String`, and not an `int`, so you can't return `0`.

If your method was returning an `int`, you could return `0`.

But, in your case, you should maybe throw an exception instead of returning "Error" and using `System.exit()` like that:

```
public String monthString(int monthNumber) throws IllegalArgumentException {
```

and throw it:

```
    default:
        System.out.println("Fatal Error");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect month number");
```

Or even better, you can directly use what is provided by Java to implement your function:

```
public static String monthString(final int monthNumber) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber-1);
    return c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.ENGLISH);
}
```